# Как ускорить рекурсию на python?

Tags: python, оптимизация, рекурсия

```py
with open('input.txt', 'r') as y:

    num = int(y.readline())

    def recurs(cycle, num):
        if num == 0:
            return 1
        c = 0
        for i in range(1, cycle):
            if num - i < 0:
                break
            c += recurs(i, num - i)
        return c
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:

    f.write(str(recurs(num + 1, num)))
```

Сам код полностью рабочий, но при проверке на сайте acmp.ru ([задача 16: лесенка](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=16)) превышает лимит по времени на 9м тесте. После проведенной мною проверки код начинает уходить за лимит времени при вводимом числе 100 и выше. Как ускорить код?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

немного измененный способ gord1402, который работает чуть побыстрее (проверял на N = 1000):

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def recurs(cycle, num):
    return 1 if num == 0 else sum(recurs(i, num - i) for i in range(1, min(cycle, num + 1)))
```

вот так еще чуть-чуть побыстрее:

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def recurs(cycle, num):
    if num == 0:
        return 1
    c = 0
    for i in range(1, min(cycle, num + 1)):
        c += recurs(i, num - i)
    return c
```

Comment: `@functools.cache`

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете использовать `functools` для этого:

```py
import functools

with open('input.txt', 'r') as y:
    num = int(y.readline())
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def recurs(cycle, num):
        if num == 0:
            return 1
        c = 0
        for i in range(1, cycle):
            if num - i < 0:
                break
            c += recurs(i, num - i)
        return c
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(recurs(num + 1, num)))
```

Comment: Помогло, теперь буду знать. Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

Не то, чтобы это было принципиально для данной задачи, у нее достаточно демократичное ограничение аргумента, но решение можно еще значительно ускорить, избавившись от лишнего цикла подсчета суммы.

Для этого нужно вести динамику по количеству кубиков и **максимальной** ширине основания, на которой можно было бы построить такую лесенку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, имея 9 кубиков можно построить 5 разных лесенок шириной не более 6.
Для этого возьмем все лесенки, которые можно построить из этих кубиков, но с меньшей шириной (не более 5)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А после отложим 6 кубиков для основания, и из оставшихся сложим все возможные лесенки, опять же с меньшей шириной

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и положим их на это основание

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получим 5 лесенок из 9 кубиков с шириной основания не больше 6

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И для этого достаточно будет сложить всего два значения - количество лесенок из 9 кубиков с шириной не больше 5 и количество лесенок из 3 кубиков шириной не больше 5

Делать это рекурсивно с кешированием или таблично – решайте сами.

<sub>Тонкий момент: да, из нуля кубиков можно построить **одну** лесенку нулевой ширины – пустую лесенку.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

немного считирил чтоб написать более быстрый алгоритм:

1. сгенерировал первые несколько членов последовательности

   ```
    1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 32, 38, 46, 54, 64, 76, 89, 104, 122, 142, 165, 192, 222, 256, 296, 340, 390, 448, 512, 585, 668, 760, 864, 982, 1113,
   ```

и отправил их в wolfram alpha, чтоб посмотреть, будет ли найдена аналитическая формула

2. была найдена к сожалению только рекурентная:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=1%5C%2844%29+1%5C%2844%29+2%5C%2844%29+2%5C%2844%29+3%5C%2844%29+4%5C%2844%29+5%5C%2844%29+6%5C%2844%29+8%5C%2844%29+10%5C%2844%29+12%5C%2844%29+15%5C%2844%29+18%5C%2844%29+22%5C%2844%29+27%5C%2844%29+32%5C%2844%29+38%5C%2844%29+46%5C%2844%29+54%5C%2844%29+64%5C%2844%29+76%5C%2844%29+89%5C%2844%29+104%5C%2844%29+122%5C%2844%29+142%5C%2844%29+165%5C%2844%29+192%5C%2844%29+222%5C%2844%29+256%5C%2844%29+296%5C%2844%29+340%5C%2844%29+390%5C%2844%29+448%5C%2844%29+512%5C%2844%29+585%5C%2844%29+668%5C%2844%29+760%5C%2844%29+864%5C%2844%29+982%5C%2844%29+1113%5C%2844%29

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. которую я и закодил

код:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

import functools
@functools.cache
def a(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        a_sum = sum([sigma(k) * a(n - k) for k in range(1, n + 1)])
        b_sum = 2 * sum([sigma(k) * a(n - 2 * k) for k in range(1, n // 2 + 1)])
        return (a_sum - b_sum) // n


@functools.cache
def sigma(n):
    return sum([i for i in range(1, n + 1) if n % i == 0])
```

В итоге для N = 1000 скорость возросла в 25 раз и время выполнения уменьшилось с 6,4 сек, до 0,25 сек :)

Ну и главный недостаток - требование к длине рекурсий увеличенное - так что пришлось повышать предел через `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)`